# Using Scala from Java: passing functions as parameters

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Consider the following Scala code:

```
package scala_java
object MyScala {
  def setFunc(func: Int => String) {
    func(10)
  }
}
```

Now in Java, I would have liked to use `MyScala` as:

```
package scala_java;
public class MyJava {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyScala.setFunc(myFunc);  // This line gives an error
    }
    public static String myFunc(int someInt) {
        return String.valueOf(someInt);
    }
}
```

However, the above does not work (as expected since Java does not allow functional programming). What is the easiest workaround to pass a function in Java? I would like a generic solution that works with functions having arbitrary number of parameters.

EDIT: Does Java 8 have any better syntax than the classic solutions discussed below?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to manually instantiate a `Function1` in Java. Something like:

```
final Function1<Integer, String> f = new Function1<Integer, String>() {
    public int $tag() {
        return Function1$class.$tag(this);
    }

    public <A> Function1<A, String> compose(Function1<A, Integer> f) {
        return Function1$class.compose(this, f);
    }

    public String apply(Integer someInt) {
        return myFunc(someInt);
    }
};
MyScala.setFunc(f);
```

This is taken from [Daniel Spiewak’s “Interop Between Java and Scala” article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala).

Comment: Be sure to check out the article and Daniel's `FunUtils` class in the comments, which helps remove some of the needed boilerplate for `$tag` and `compose`.

Comment: That is very informative. I had seen the article before but not read the comments.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet it seems like the Daniel Spiewak's link is broken.

Comment: @Gautham Check out Seth's answer, it's better than mine. Daniel's link is now about 10 years old…

Answer (score 75):

In the `scala.runtime` package, there are abstract classes named `AbstractFunction1` and so on for other arities. To use them from Java you only need to override `apply`, like this:

```
Function1<Integer, String> f = new AbstractFunction1<Integer, String>() {
    public String apply(Integer someInt) {
        return myFunc(someInt);
    }
};
```

If you're on Java 8 and want to use Java 8 lambda syntax for this, check out https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is the most helpful of all! Trying to implement Function1, Java tells me I have to implement dozens of methods - Function1 has specializations for several primitive types.

Comment: This *is* the answer you are looking for :) Also check out http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/java.html

Comment: Note that if you're compiling for Android or iOS, you won't be able to use scala-java8-compat because retrolambda can only modify what you have source files for. Nor does the source have the lambda bridge classes (JFunction0 etc) because they are code-generated from the sbt directly to .class files. Possibly there is a way to include the .class files in your project where retrolambda can modify them, but I haven't invested the effort to figure that out.

Comment: If your function parameter takes no parameters, you need to type an AbstractFunction1 with BoxedUnit; similarly, if it returns Unit, you need to type the return valies with BoxedUnit and return BoxedUnit.UNIT in your lambda. i.e. `new AbstractFunction1<BoxedUnit, BoxedUnit>() {  public BoxedUnit apply(BoxedUnit unit) { /* . . . */ return BoxedUnit.UNIT; } }`

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way for me is to defined a *java* interface like:

```
public interface JFunction<A,B> {
  public B compute( A a );
}
```

Then modify your scala code, overloading `setFunc` to accept also `JFunction` objects such as:

```
object MyScala {
  // API for scala
  def setFunc(func: Int => String) {
    func(10)
  }
  // API for java
  def setFunc(jFunc: JFunction[Int,String]) {
    setFunc( (i:Int) => jFunc.compute(i) )
  }
}
```

You will naturally use the first definition from scala, but still be able to use the second one from java:

```
public class MyJava {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    MyScala.setFunc(myFunc);  // This line gives an error
  }

  public static final JFunction<Integer,String> myFunc = 
    new JFunction<Integer,String>() {
      public String compute( Integer a ) {
        return String.valueOf(a);
      }
    };

}
```

Comment: @Jus12. Thanks, that's fixed.

Comment: Actually, Scala's functions are *already* implemented as a SAM type behind the scenes. You can therefore directly implement `FunctionN` (as per Jean-Philippe's answer) and don't need to introduce your own `JFunction` type.

Comment: I disagree, while you can directly instantiate a scala function from java, the resulting code is rather ugly. If you just want to access some scala code sometimes, it is ok. But if you to provide a java API, you'll have a nicer code by adding some higher level interface and scala methods designed for the java API. It will help a lot to cope with the lack of implicit resolutions for example.

Comment: This is fine as long as you have the Scala source.

Comment: @paradigmatic - Even then, there's a strong argument to be made for using something like the `Function` type from Google guava, instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @Kevin Wright. Of course, or even from FunctionalJava. That was just an example of what could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a solution, a little library: https://github.com/eirslett/sc8

You wrap your Java 8 lambda in F(...) and then it's converted to a Scala function.