# Add to Scala List of type List[(Int) => Unit] from Java

Tags: java, scala

I am working on a project which contains both Scala and Java code. I have a Scala method defined as :

```
var responseListeners: List[(Int) => Unit]

  def addResponseListener(onResponse: Int => Unit) {
    responseListeners ::= onResponse
  }
```

And this method is called in Scala as:

```
addResponseListener(id => processors(id).wakeup())
```

Now I have some Java code in which I have access to the `processors` array, but how do I call the `addResponseListener(onResponse: Int => Unit)` from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AbstractFunction1` from `scala.runtime`:

```
AbstractFunction1<scala.lang.Int, Void> f = (i) -> doWorkWith(i);
```

In the event that `doWorkWith` does not return `void` you'll need to `return null;` from the lambda:

```
i -> {
  doWorkWith(i);
  return null;
}
```

See also:

- [Using Scala from Java: passing functions as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545066/using-scala-from-java-passing-functions-as-parameters)
- [Convert Scala Unit to Java Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171262/convert-scala-unit-to-java-void)